# How to associate data with owl object property to link individuals

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology, reasoning

I have following ontology

```xml
    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/POC#Person"/>
    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/POC#Vehicle"/>
    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/POC#drives"/>

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/POC#Driver">
        <owl:equivalentClass>
            <owl:Class>
                <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/POC#Person"/>
                    <owl:Restriction>
                        <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/POC#drives"/>
                        <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/POC#Vehicle"/>
                    </owl:Restriction>
                </owl:intersectionOf>
            </owl:Class>
        </owl:equivalentClass>
    </owl:Class>
```

The actual data is stored in relational database. (It could come from object database also in future.) I want to associate the data with the above ontology classes and perform reasoning over it to find out all the drivers.

I am able to connect person and car with the tables in the database. How do I associate data with "drives", which is stored in separate table with car id and person id as foreign keys, to associate the individuals of person and vehicle?

Comment: Without seeing anything about your actual database or how you're "connecting" things, we can't really offer any concrete help.  If you can "connect" the rows of tables to individuals, why is "connecting" the rows of another table to object property assertions significantly different?

Comment: I have three tables Person, Car and CarOwner. Person table has person id, name and other info. Car table has car id, name and other info columns. Car table represents a car model and not a particular car instance. CarOwner is a many to many table with car id and person id as foreign keys. My data could come from object database in future, so I am not able to use R2RML. I can map drives relation to CarOwner but  I am not able to understand how to make use of foreign key relation to say person id is coming from person. Hope this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I got it. Basically I need to add a triple "**POC#person/1 POC#drives POC#vehicle/7**". I can use my many to many table to do this. In future if data is stored in object database I can use the reference in the similar fashion.

Comment: Good work in finding a solution to your problem!  You may find [A Direct Mapping of Relational Data to RDF](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdb-direct-mapping/) useful for some guidelines here.  It sounds like you're using many of the same approaches.